# how to load image cases to measure ROI?

Tags: python

I am trying to apply [this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1ywL.png) to get the cases I want to measure:

```py
def get_cases(data_dir):
image_folders = os.listdir(data_dir)
image_folders = [f for f in image_f01ders if not f.startswith('.') and '.' not in f]
desired_cases = pd.read_exce1('data/df.xlsm')
desired_cases = desired_cases.query("vetting == 'Y'")
desired_image_ids = desired_cases['ID']
images_to_measure = []
for img in image_folders:
    first_ = img.find('.')
    if int(img[first_+1]) in desired_image_ids.unique():
       images_to_measure.append
images_to_measure = [os.path.join(data_dir, f) for f in images_to_measure]
return images_to_measure
```

However, when I run this, it throws the following error,

```
    cases = get_cases(data_dir)
    File "measure.py", line 70, in get_cases
    if int(img[first_+1]) in desired_image_ids.unique():
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'A'
```

Could someone explain to me why? And how to fix it? Does this have to do with the folder format? or how I find the img files?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please paste the code in the body of your question, rather than in an image.

Answer (score 0):

the value that `img[first_+1]` returns is `'A'`. it is likely that the number is in base 16. you should pass the number 16 as the 2nd argument to int function. (`int(img[first_+1],16)`).
 Doing so will convert the value to an integer from the base 16. 
note that if the int function is called without the 2nd argument, it will take the number as a base 10.

if another error comes up, it is possible that something else is wrong.